# Magento 2 Create temporary table for url_rewrite

Tags: magento2.3, url-rewrite

Is anyone can help me with my issue causing the database usage in 100%.

Upon checking the process lists this query mostly run and tons of id inserted

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_select_lXkeC0rXb1RZSecc1r2ONOHTLQ611c2h` (PRIMARY KEY(`url_rewrite_id`),INDEX `HASHKEY_ENTITY_STORE` USING HASH(`hash_key`),INDEX `ENTITY_STORE` USING HASH(`entity_id`,`store_id`)) ENGINE=`INNODB` IGNORE (SELECT `e`.*, CONCAT(e.store_id,'_', e.entity_id) AS `hash_key` FROM `url_rewrite` AS `e` WHERE (entity_type = 'product') AND (entity_id IN('582', '584', '585', '589', '590', '591', '592', '595', '596', '599', '614', '624', '647', '648', '818', '831', '2974', '3276', '5092', '5094', '5110', '5114', '5128', '5148', '5162', '5196', '5200', '5206', '5210', '5212', '5224', '5234', '5238', '5242', '5246', '5250', '5260', '5266', '5278', '5284', '5296', '5300', '5306', '5318', '5324', '5338', '5344', '5356', '5364', '5378', '5382', '5392', '5400', '5440', '5446', '5490', '5494', '5498', '5518', '5598', '5744', '5832', '5883', '5912', '5927', '5932', '5936', '5942', '5978', '6008', '6018', '6050', '6090', '6094', '6122', '6124', '6146', '6148', '6184', '6198', '6204', '6206', '6215', '6224', '6226', '6228', '6238', '6260', '6268', '6278', '6286', '6298', '6310', '6312', '6326', '6334', '6348', '6352', '6374', '6380', '6406', '6410', '6440', '6456', '6484', '6498', '6505', '6520', '6526', '6532', '6538', '6552', '6562', '6568', '6598', '6604', '6614', '6620', '6626', '6632', '6670', '6798', '6862', '6914', '6922', '6928', '6934', '6938', '6946', '6950', '6960', '6962', '6968', '6994', '7013', '7088', '7112', '7147', '7202', '7248', '7424', '7754', '8281', '11077', '11083', '11249', '11381', '11481', '11674', '11781', '11787', '11822', '11829', '11877', '12321', '12493', '12498', '13799', '15445', '15990', '16961', '19065', '19537', '19539', '19545', '19547', '19549', '19551', '19568', '19578', '19595', '19603', '19613', '19631', '19641', '19643', '19695', '19721', '19757', '19776', '19802', '19804', '19808', '19816', '19832', '19840', '19842', '19850', '19891', '22816', '23221', '23225', '23409', '23459', '23479', '23600', '26030', '26836', '27143', '27147', '27161', '27197', '27257', '27329', '27563', '27599', '27858', '27880', '27885', '28330', '28574', '28576', '28578', '28746', '28783', '29061', '29110', '29178', '29185', '29272', '29372', '29898', '29900', '29941', '29966', '30026', '30057', '30184', '30294', '30357', '30455', '30550', '30552', '30731', '30734', '30745', '30791', '30793', '30956', '31181', '31207', '31236', '31292', '31516', '31652', '31984', '32207', '32279', '32343', '32403', '32440', '32557', '32705', '32731', '32799', '32984', '33046', '33302', '33688', '33863', '33915', '34221', '34327', '34330', '34641', '34643', '34645', '34647', '34804', '34873', '35005', '35439', '35602', '35958', '35962', '35963', '35964', '36154', '36248', '36370', '36734', '37053', '37519', '37530', '37540', '37576', '38102', '38259', '38270', '38305', '38392', '38562', '38575', '38600', '38819', '38842', '38930', '38932', '39258', '39264', '39299', '39566', '40052', '40115', '40121', '40123', '40125', '40127', '40128', '40130', '40322', '40354', '40366', '40825', '40827', '41216', '41316', '41485', '41506', '41516', '41750', '41754', '41765', '41834', '41839', '41849', '41854', '41856', '41963', '42050', '42210', '42579', '43189', '43259', '43421', '43587', '43594', '43597', '43599', '43607', '43757', '43896', '43948', '44046', '44622', '44703', '44706', '44995', '45053', '45060', '45141', '45170', '45173', '45199', '45262', '45336', '45361', '45566', '45568', '45668', '45670', '46052', '46168', '46295', '46382', '46503', '46531', '46535', '46544', '46546', '46550', '46586', '47106', '47114', '47117', '47344', '47423', '47546', '47823', '47841', '47843', '47846', '47854', '47933', '48060', '48086', '48114', '48374', '48446', '48475', '48477', '48481', '48483', '48486', '48493', '48496', '48498', '48502', '48509', '48512', '48516', '48519', '48526', '48535', '48539', '48541', '48542', '48543', '48545', '48547', '48566', '48593', '48594', '48595', '48601', '48605', '48609', '48617', '48656', '48667', '48703', '48780', '48781', '48793', '48857', '48859', '48864', '48892', '48909', '48943', '48955', '48963', '48964', '48966', '48967', '48996', '49012', '49013', '49025', '49050', '49053', '49056', '49208', '49210', '49246', '49249', '49252', '49322', '49457', '49478', '49480', '49504', '49518', '49519', '49584', '49591', '49617', '49618', '49626', '49694', '49744', '49749', '49801', '49806', '49809', '49810', '49811', '49854', '49893', '49976', '49990', '50133', '50136', '50137', '50146', '50234', '50294', '50310', '50387', '50560', '50586', '50803', '50806', '50912', '50996', '51020', '51799', '52191', '52204', '52265', '52266', '52324', '52348', '52403', '52425', '52429', '52499', '52513', '52516', '52518', '52549', '52819', '52843', '53111', '53403', '53498', '53663', '54014', '54408', '54418', '54454', '54456', '54457', '54525', '54699', '54701', '54768', '54836', '54893', '54926', '55079', '55136', '55138', '55541', '55543', '55549', '55553', '55855', '55874', '55981', '55986', '56116', '56117', '56151', '56180', '56474', '56645', '56646', '56711', '56757', '56820', '56966', '57370', '57375', '57378', '57387', '57540', '57544', '57547', '57557', '57563', '57565', '57567', '57649', '57654', '57659', '57663', '57719', '57724', '57735', '57739', '57741', '57752', '57762', '57767', '57776', '58410', '58494', '58586', '58610', '58620', '58625', '58907', '59077', '59376', '59391', '59396', '59507', '59530', '59566', '59610', '59618', '59834', '59926', '59962', '60061', '60112', '60113', '60166', '60339', '60360', '60361', '60362', '60521', '60533', '60564', '60674', '60677', '60810', '60909', '61060', '61191', '61192', '61216', '61309', '61494', '61978', '62131', '62133', '62304', '62412', '62435', '62535', '62539', '62584', '62868', '62941', '63135', '63246', '63249', '63256', '63258', '63260', '63261', '63263', '63264', '63267', '63742', '63743', '63770', '63772', '64065', '64295', '64408', '64415', '64517', '64523', '64748', '64774', '64864', '65112', '65414', '65537', '65550', '65743', '65768', '65769', '66293', '66317', '66525', '66612', '66683', '66854', '66890', '66895', '66897', '66911', '67039', '67078', '67080', '67151', '67223', '67387', '67407', '67412', '67421', '67625', '67884', '68333', '68642', '68659', '68684', '68743', '69028', '69057', '69102', '69157', '69250', '69292', '69410', '69422', '69959', '70208', '70236', '70277', '70540', '70573', '71072', '71099', '71105', '71489', '71519', '71757', '71810', '72346', '72775', '72817', '72818', '72822', '72827', '72888', '72893', '72932', '72945', '72948', '73164', '73173', '73229', '73642', '73644', '73738', '73785', '74015', '74267', '74268', '74272', '74323', '74500', '75353', '75543', '75623', '75625', '76430', '76462', '76670', '76796', '76844', '76990', '77648', '77683', '77760', '78044', '78454', '79279', '79792', '79978', '80194', '80308', '80597', '80988', '80998', '81015', '81092', '81292', '81434', '81441', '81443', '81741', '82000', '82024', '82066', '82103', '82721', '82789', '83077', '83548', '83553', '83584', '83592', '83593', '83627', '83853', '83867', '83938', '83961', '84404', '84493', '84602', '84643', '84679', '85014', '85030', '85049', '85227', '85389', '85468', '85528', '85877', '85915', '86204', '86222', '86502', '86528', '86650', '86803', '86968', '87117', '87119', '87121', '87152', '87414', '87424', '87569', '87570', '87800', '87992', '88320', '88747', '88855', '89058', '89264', '89676', '89887', '90866', '91399', '91409', '91422', '91690', '91697', '91860', '91876', '92207', '92529', '93739', '93834', '94393', '94757', '94762', '94774', '94790', '95160', '96152', '96249', '96269', '96373', '96633', '97247', '97350', '97361', '97400', '97651', '97656', '97766', '97788', '97821', '97917', '97922', '97924', '97925', '98008', '98092', '98132', '98151', '98275', '98540', '98604', '98969', '99005', '99170', '99175', '99242', '99785', '99837', '99856', '100093', '100097', '100135', '100175', '100197', '100210', '100460', '100473', '100636', '100912', '100973', '100975', '101509', '101553', '101693', '101751', '101880', '102195', '102378', '102386', '102497', '102511', '102760', '102818', '102826', '103006', '103129', '103213', '103306', '103310', '103327', '103331', '103335', '103341', '103462', '103468', '103475', '103492', '103644', '103677', '104167', '104275', '104279', '104639', '104878', '104882', '104888', '104901', '104904', '104937', '104938', '104939', '105209', '105260', '105375', '105377', '105382', '105400', '105464', '105473', '106033', '106253', '106255', '106260', '106263', '106271', '106481', '106501', '106605', '106650', '107122', '107296', '107605', '107675', '107712', '107786', '108071', '108296', '108359', '108362', '108365', '108366', '108474', '108496', '108699', '108752', '108964', '108984', '109022', '109070', '109389', '109394', '109402', '109434', '109535', '109593', '109628', '109632', '109699', '109707', '109833', '109896', '109900', '110210', '110696', '110705', '110788', '110931', '110946', '111027', '111176', '111186', '111214', '111215', '111287', '111289', '111320', '111321', '111511', '111514', '111739', '111749', '111918', '112234', '112309', '112323', '112375', '112558', '112661', '112758', '112966', '113433', '113479', '113585', '113794', '113888', '113893', '114020', '114098', '114174', '114208', '114235', '114246', '114288', '114304', '114392', '114403', '114451', '114494', '114598', '114622', '114654', '114720', '115188', '115262', '115264', '115342', '115343', '115345', '115368', '115488', '115697', '115698', '116032', '116229', '116234', '116249', '116323', '116511', '116662', '116817', '116878', '117039', '117102', '117107', '117442', '117483', '117489', '117491', '117494', '117501', '117504', '117520', '117578', '117626', '117669', '117988', '118073', '118075', '118101', '118241', '118298', '118380', '118453', '118469', '118496', '118514', '118546', '118660', '118769', '118963', '118973', '119006', '119112', '119118', '119166', '119252', '119316', '119324', '119349', '119355', '119389', '119496', '119515', '119794', '119844', '119878', '120051', '120174', '120309', '120325', '120375', '120395', '120399', '120411', '120707', '120771', '120778', '120787', '121132', '121191', '121281', '121295', '121363', '121365', '121403', '121410', '121416', '121453', '121519', '121617', '121710', '121711', '121712', '121714', '121715', '121799', '121942', '122080', '122115', '122117', '122145', '122147', '122148', '122225', '122227', '122574', '122716', '122723', '122815', '122840', '122922', '122985', '123139', '123144', '123148', '123239', '123716', '123757', '123912', '123940', '123994', '123998', '124132', '124190', '124437', '124504', '124675', '124790', '124795', '125052', '125062', '125145', '125186', '125252', '125388', '125474', '125750', '125865', '125904', '125939', '125983', '125991', '125998', '126092', '126184', '126324', '126395', '126489', '126521', '126690', '126757', '126793', '126907', '126928', '126986', '127033', '127043', '127059', '127111', '127134', '127194', '127293', '127334', '127372', '127377', '127379', '127513', '127517', '127530', '127544', '127628', '127656', '127664', '127666', '127744', '127794', '127795', '127821', '127830', '127970', '127976', '128012', '128014', '128167', '128379', '128394', '128420', '128474', '128609', '128655', '128689', '128697', '128746', '128785', '128893', '128910', '128941', '128956', '129061', '129362', '129483', '129677', '129682', '129706', '129713', '129773', '129944', '130078', '130312', '130544', '130573', '130588', '130608', '130782', '130784', '130836', '130906', '130992', '130999', '131099', '131236', '131430', '131587', '131634', '131671', '131677', '131712', '131752', '131802', '131829', '131837', '131893', '131905', '132072', '132092', '132147', '132201', '132407', '132560', '132606', '132627', '132663', '132732', '132734', '132813', '132815', '132821', '132867', '132952', '133044', '133258', '133273', '133309', '133328', '133407', '133412', '133455', '133512', '133527', '133653', '133694', '133785', '133804', '133995', '134045', '134090', '134112', '134183', '134260', '134278', '134340', '134451', '134495', '134501', '134543', '134550', '134553', '134558', '134565', '134566', '134593', '134596', '134599', '134603', '134605', '134620', '134767', '134824', '134968', '135134', '135137', '135221', '135236', '135248', '135281', '135315', '135354', '135391', '135394', '135505', '135666', '135857', '136065', '136260', '136425', '136474', '136505', '136508', '136510', '136554', '136566', '136624', '136677', '136707', '136932', '137187', '137196', '137239', '137411', '137490', '137574', '137578', '137645', '137650', '137672', '137942', '138204', '138211', '138283', '138600', '138633', '138635', '138812', '138825', '138826', '138846', '138865', '138867', '138870', '138937', '139061', '139108', '139143', '139219', '139277', '139288', '139289', '139408', '139463', '139470', '139485', '139551', '139590', '139644', '139720', '139776', '139787', '139923', '139943', '139997', '140001', '140041', '140069', '140076', '140077', '140099', '140108', '140149', '140228', '140304', '140306', '140314', '140406', '140443', '140487', '140501', '140505', '140507', '140509', '140560', '140717', '140878', '141000', '141029', '141038', '141132', '141305', '141334', '141592', '141610', '141641', '142022', '142143', '142158', '142166', '142218', '142243', '142254', '142458', '142521', '142569', '142573', '142746', '142825', '142848', '142866', '142983', '143009', '143073', '143080', '143145', '143159', '143464', '143480', '143559', '143560', '143567', '143569', '143575', '143577', '143780', '143832', '143934', '144009', '144107', '144116', '144199', '144250', '144398', '144407', '144413', '144466', '144480', '144484', '144485', '144589', '144716', '144723', '144778', '144806', '144829', '145202', '145256', '145282', '145398', '145445', '145449', '145499', '145501', '145519', '145665', '145845', '145855', '145999', '146037', '146237', '146298', '146428', '146433', '146554')))
```

Is there a way can disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to login in the backend then go to `store->configuration->general->web->Search Engines Optimization` and set the field **Use Web Server Rewrites** to **No** and clear the cache.